# Unity 2D chest player detection

Tags: unity-game-engine

so what i wan't to do is my chest in my 2D game to be able to detect when a player enter on a certain range and display a text displaying "press e to pick item".But i don't know what to use to detect the player in the range of the chest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//set this to width of chest
int chest_width = 5;

GameObject player = GameObject.Find ("Player"); 
Transform playerTransform = player.transform; 
// get player position 
Vector3 position = playerTransform.position

int x_dis =gameObject.transform.position.x-position.x;
If(x_dis<0){
    x_dis*=-1;
}

if(x_dis<chest_width){
//IT IS IN THE CHEST REGION
}
```

Comment: Oh i didn't know that you can use a GameObject.find. Thanks dude

Comment: Yeh then just subtract the x positions and see if the distance is within the chest.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to detect it.

1. Check the distance of the difference between player & Chest.
2. Use OnTriggerEnter2D for Chest and make that collider bigger than Chest.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
GameObject player;
float interactRange;

void Update()
{
    DetectIfPlayerIsInRange();
}

void DetectIfPlayerIsInRange()
{
    if (Vector2.Distance(player.transform.position, this.transform.position) < interactRange)
    {
        DisplayInteraction();
    }
}

void DisplayInteraction()
{
    // code to display your interaction 
    // such as press e to pick up or e to open chest etc...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i wanted to do is for a top down game, but i think i'll use the GO.find("") and with the coordinate, apply the arthmetic circle coordinate like (x-a)²+(y-b)²=R² where x and y are the coordinate of the player and a, b the coordinates of the center of the circle.
So if the result is < or = to R² then, my event will occurs.

Comment: `Vector2.Distance(player, chest)` will get you the distance between two gameobjects. Easiest would be to use a CircleCollider2D and trigger code when the user enters the circle collider.

Comment: Yes, but the collider will, stop the player on move, right ?

Comment: Oh i see,what i need to do is add a collider and just put it in "Is trigger" ?

Comment: Indeed! A trigger will not block colliders, it will simply "trigger" and run your code when another collider enters its zone! :)